# If $\langle x_n\rangle$ satisfies $\|x_{n+2} - x_{n+1}\| \lt \|x_{n+1} - x_n\|$, can it be a Cauchy sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose $\langle x_n\rangle$ is a sequence on Cartesian coordinate system.
If $\|x_{n+2} - x_{n+1}\| \le r\|x_{n+1} - x_n\|$ $(r \lt 1)$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$ then $\langle x_n \rangle $ is a Cauchy sequence.

Then, how about if $\langle x_n\rangle $ satisfies $\|x_{n+2} - x_{n+1}\| \lt \|x_{n+1} - x_n\|$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$ ?

My idea : Let $a_n = \|x_{n+1} - x_n\|$. Then $\langle a_n\rangle $ is a monotonically decreasing sequence, and $a_n \gt 0$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$. Therefore, there exists $\lim a_n = L$. However, there's a chance $L \gt 0$.

As you can see above, my idea is very abstract and I'm even not sure whether it is right. Please help me to make a more rigorous proof.

Comment: Hint: In $\mathbb{R}$, $x_n=\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if $L=0$, you can't be sure that $\langle x_n\rangle $ is a Cauchy sequence. If you look at the proof for the $r<1$ case, what you need is that $\sum_n a_n <\infty$. So for example, if $x_n=\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}\frac{1}{k}$, then
$$\frac{1}{n+2}=\left|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}\right|<\left|x_{n+1}-x_{n}\right|=\frac{1}{n+1},$$
but $\langle x_n\rangle$ is not a Cauchy sequence.

In fact, this example can easily be modified to obtain a case where $L>0$ ; you can simply define $x_n$ as the sum of the terms of some sequence that is decreasing but doesn't converge to $0$. For example, you can take $x_n=\sum_{1\leq k\leq n} \frac{k+1}{2k}$, and you will find that $L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n+2}{2(n+1)}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Very nice counterexample. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, since the sequence does not define a contraction. As an exercise, you can consider the following series, which is a sequence of partial sums, $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$. You can show that this series satisfies the condition given in the question, but it is not convergent since it is a $1/n^p$ series with $p = 1$, which is harmonic series that is well known to be divergent.